# how to update database from datagridview bound by linq query and entity model?

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, data-binding, datagridview

I bind a datagridview from a linq query, but I don't know how to make it updated to database when users makes changes on the datagridview.

```
var q = from w in dowacodbEntities.worksheets
                    where w.ContractForm_id.Equals(g_ContractID)
                    orderby w.id
                    select new
                               {
                                   w.id,
                                   w.UnitPrice,
                                   w.LabourCost
                               };
            BindingSource bindingSource = new BindingSource(); // use bindingsource
            bindingSource.DataSource = q.ToList(); // convert linq query to bindingsource
            dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource; // add bindingsource to datagridview
```

p/s : I'm using C# winform

Comment: are you using windows form or web?

Comment: you should probably call some save method or acceptchanges method on the bindingSource object. Please try and show some code and ask if still does not work :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is the same problem

[WinForms DataGridView - update database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2623548/winforms-datagridview-update-database)

Comment: no it's not the same as he is working with bindingSource object